Processing key and value of object using *ngFor
I am stuck on how to get the key and value of an object in Angular while using *ngFor for iterating over the object.
Interface:
export interface CustomColumn {
    [key: string]: boolean
}

AppComponent.ts
export class AppComponent {
  service = inject(DataService);
  displayedColumns: CustomColumn[] = [];
  respData = {} as ResponseData;
  ...

  async fetchServiceDatails(criteria: string) {
    await this.service.getDatails(criteria).subscribe({
      next: (resp) => {
        this.respData = resp;
        if (this.respData && this.respData.data) {
          this.displayedColumns = Object.entries(this.respData.data.entities).map(function (entry) {
            let customColumn: CustomColumn = {};
            customColumn = {
              [entry]: true
            };
            return customColumn;
          });
        }
      },
      error: (e) => {
        console.log('Error in fetching serviceDetails: ', e);
      }
    });
  } 
}

AppComponent.html
    <ul class="dropdown-menu checkbox-menu allow-focus" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <li *ngFor="let item of displayedColumns | keyvalue">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" value="{{item.key}}"> {{item.key}}
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>

But what I am getting is [object Object] in the output:


I wonder if you turn on typescript checking or not.
Your code can't run because of error type "A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'
(parameter) entry: [string, string]"
your entries 'Object.entries(this.respData.data.entities)' return an array of array, so the map method will get an array as its parameter. How an array can be the key of an object?

Although I did not get you completely. However, I updated my question (removed sample data for this.respData.data.entities as it was not giving correct view). Now coming to your point: How an array can be the key of an object? Answer: If you could see customColumn = {[entry]: true} where I am building the object and adding it to displayedColumns array. And displayedColumns I am looping to build the drop down. Further I want to dynamically control the visibility of drop down items based on boolean value. Hope its clear to you !

customColumn = {[entry]: true} where I am building the object by passing string data as key and hardcoded boolean as value and adding it to displayedColumns. And looping displayedColumns to build the drop down.

Changed the implementation in AppComponent.html as below and it worked.
    <ul class="dropdown-menu checkbox-menu allow-focus" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        @for (col of displayedColumns; track $index) {
        <li *ngFor="let item of col | keyvalue">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" value=""> {{item.key}}
            </label>
        </li>
    }
    </ul>


Believing this.respData.data.entities is array of string like:
const respData.data.entities = ["column1" , "column2"];

and you want output like following:

make following change in how you prepare data for the displayedColumns
async fetchServiceDatails(criteria: string) {
 await this.service.getDatails(criteria).subscribe({
 next: (resp) => {
  this.respData = resp;

  if (this.respData?.data?.entities?.length > 0) {
    const customColumn: { [key: string]: boolean } = {};
    this.respData.data.entities.forEach((entry: string) => {
      const key = entry;
      customColumn[key] = true;
    });
    this.displayedColumns = customColumn;
  }
 },
  error: (e) => {
   console.log('Error in fetching serviceDetails: ', e);
  }
 });
}

After making following change let me know if it works or not :-)

You can ask this question by posting a comment in the question itself, instead of adding it as answer. Now coming to your question this.respData.data.entities will list of string data. Which we are processing and wrapping in under an Object named customColumn. For details pls refer the question's comment section

I didn't have that privilege , I have updated my answer please have look now.

Thanks for the input Utsav. I doubt, how your logic will capture all the columns inside forEach as you are overriding values of customColumn inside the loop. Another point is instead of this this.displayedColumns = customColumn; you need to push the each column entry inside the loop. Can you pls re-check your answer.
